# Finding cumulative probability distribution

Tags: probability

***Question***
Probability Density function:

$$f(x,y) = 3x, \quad 0 \le y \le x \le 1$$

$f(x,y) = 0$ elsewhere.

Find $P(X\le 1/2, Y\le 1/3)$

***Solution***
$$\int_0^\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\frac{1}{3}3x\,dx\,dy=0.1065$$

I cannot figure out why the limits of the integral are like this. I would have guess they should have been reversed, such that, limit for $x$ should have been from $\frac{1}{2}$ to $0$ and not the other way around.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I do not see why you want the limits reversed. After all, this is a positive function in the given range, so integrating from $\frac 12$ to $0$ would give a negative answer, while probabilities can't be negative.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг : I think you misunderstood the question.

Comment: You have $0\le y\le1,$ and you should also have some bounds for $x. \qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Your answer below is correct. However, I felt that the person above was arguing about the limits of the integral i.e. why it is $\int_0^{\frac 12}$ and not $\int_{\frac 12}^0$. That is the concern I attempted to address in my comment. If the OP now confirms that this was incorrect, then I will remove these comments. +1.

Comment: The problem only makes sense of you restrict x to some interval like $(0,(\frac 2 3)^{1/2})$. This is needed to make sure that f is a density function.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable inputs and sorry about the confusion. I meant to say that I thought the solution should have been: $$
\Pr\left(X\le\frac 1 2\ \,\ Y \le \frac 1 3\right) = \int_0^{1/3} \left( \int_0^{1/2} 3x\,dx \right) \,dy
$$ even though the book stated the solution is : $$\int_0^\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\frac{1}{3}3x\,dx\,dy=0.1065$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>The proposed solution is wrong; what you thought it should be is right.</s>
$$
\require{cancel} \xcancel{
\Pr\left(X\le\frac 1 2\ \&\ Y \le \frac 1 3\right) = \int_0^{1/3} \left( \int_0^{1/2} 3x\,dx \right) \,dy=0.1065}
$$
The question has been edited since I posted this. We are now told $y\le x,$ so we have $0\le y\le x\le1.$
\begin{align}
\Pr\left(X\le\frac 1 2\ \&\ Y \le \frac 1 3\right) & = \iint\limits_{\{\,(x,y) \,:\, 0\,\le\,y\,\le 1/3\ \&\ y\,\le\,x\,\le\,1\,\}} 3x \, d(x,y) \\[10pt]
& = \begin{cases} \text{either } & \displaystyle \int_0^{1/3} \left( \int_y^{1/2} 3x\,dx \right) \, dy \\[10pt]
\text{or } & \displaystyle \int_0^{1/3} \left( \int_0^x 3x\,dy \right) \,dx + \int_{1/3}^{1/2} \left( \int_0^{1/3} 3x \,dy \right) \,dx
\end{cases} \\[20pt]
& = 0. 106\,481\,481\,481\,\ldots
\end{align}
The parentheses enclosing the inner integrals are not obligatory, but are included in order to call attention to that which needs attention in this context.

Comment: I think this is the thing OP is asking. However without the brachets that you have some authors use a confusing notation such that the integral in OP means the same thing as this.

Comment: @HartoSaarinen : If what was intended is this integral that appears in my answer, then the notation used in the posted question is very bad notation.

Comment: I agree it's really bad. I have actually seen that notation in many lecture notes here in Finland and every time I get confused.

Comment: @HartoSaarinen, agreed. My book does not include the parenthesis with double integrals.

Comment: @Michael Hardy , agreed that's what I thought the correct answer should have been. Unfortunately, if you evaluate the integral this way, the answer comes out to 0.125 and not 0.1065. I am starting to think that the limits might have to be reversed because of this condition $$0 \le y \le x \le 1$$.

Comment: Thanks everyone. This makes sense now - I think the key is to breakdown the inequalities into separate ones for x and y and then solve for them as limits on integrals.